# Apache Alias problem, Snow Leopard

Tags: php, apache, osx-snow-leopard

I`m using Snow Leopard for web development with PHP. I have a folder in my home directory which is used as the eclipse workspace for the project. I would like to use it as my deployment directory in Apache, so that any changes that i make will be instantly visible.

For that purpose i created an Alias in httpd.conf as follow:

```
Alias /mysite/ "/Users/mysuser/workspace/mysite"
<Directory "/Users/victor/workspace/mysite">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

However, when i try to access http://localhost/mysite/index.php i get:

```
   Forbidden
   You don't have permission to access /mysite/index.php on this server.
```

I have checked the permissions of the folder and all users can read/write/execute on it.

Am i missing something ? Also, is there a better alternative to using aliases pointing to my workspace ?
Thanks, Victor.

Comment: `/Users/mysuser` vs. `/Users/victor` ?? typo?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all the folders above (most likely `/Users/mysuser`) have permissions for any to read/execute.  The execute bit when set for a directory, grants the ability to traverse its tree in order to access files or subdirectories.

To answer the second half of your question, I always use `VirtualHosts`, and define hostnames (i.e. `127.0.0.1 mysite.local`) in my `/etc/hosts` file.  This way you are less likely to have problems with using absolute paths.  Your "template" files can link to `/css/main.css` without having to worry about base path issues...

Answer (score 0):

@gnarf was correct in the first paragraph:

> Make sure that all the folders above (most likely /Users/mysuser) have permissions for any to read/execute. The execute bit when set for a directory, grants the ability to traverse its tree in order to access files or subdirectories.

Specifically, the way to fix this problem is to go to Terminal, cd to the proper directory where those files are located and type:

```
sudo chmod 0755 mysite
```

You might want to do the same to the files inside the directory if for some reason it still doesn't work.  And as a last resort, just to test that permissions aren't the issue any longer, try to chmod them to 0777 (temporarily, as this is a security hole if you leave it).

Answer (score 0):

There is a SERIOUS bug in 10.6/10.5's ALIAS/REDIRECT implementation (not to mention their lame apache setup paradigm).

Any of the "Aliases" or "Redirects" you make in Server Admin have quotes around the arguments...  as do `<DocumentRoot "XXX">`, and `<Directory "XXX">` directives... in the resulting .conf files.  I don't think ANY of these parameters are SUPPOSED to have quotes..  I've been struggling with this for so long I can't tell up from down anymore...

Solution... Set up your basic VHost structure in server admin, then stop using it!!  Go into the .conf files it has created in `/etc/apache2/Sites` and manually add your `mod_alias` directives. This is What Server Admin's output looks like..

```
Alias "/include/" "/ServiceData/Web/mabishu/include/"
Alias "/collaboration" "/usr/share/collaboration"
Alias "/error/" "/usr/share/httpd/error/"
Redirect temp "http://www.osxserversux.com/" "http://osxserver.com/"
```

This is what it SHOULD look like, and what actually works, (I think)...

```
Alias /include/ /ServiceData/Web/mabishu/include/
Alias /collaboration /usr/share/collaboration
Alias /error/ /usr/share/httpd/error/
Redirect temp http://www.osxserversux.com/ http://osxserver.com/
```

And from this point on, **NEVER hit save in "Web" in "Server Admin" again**.  If you do it will happily put all the quotes back for you!

This entire Web Administration, and specifically the "Aliases" "panel" is a hideous example of Apple faltering in their quest to make things easier.  They rename conventions, making researching solutions a nightmare, and their implementation is broken.  Not to mention they should have used mod_rewrite instead...  Top it all off with scant documentation of their proprietary setup method, and ugh!

I LOVE Apple, but some of the frustrations and lack of configuration options of Mac OS X server are really inexcusable and annnoying.